# How to full width in one button in a group

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make full with the button on right side.
I added btn-block on button element but it's dont working i don't know why.

[Jsfiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/u1r5ddu0/1/)

```
<div class="fieldset">
    <div class="field qty">
        <label class="label" for="qty"><span>Qlty</span></label>
        <div class="control control-qty-cart">
            <span class="quantity-controls quantity-minus"></span>
            <input type="number" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="1" title="Aantal" class="qty-default input-text qty" data-validate="{&quot;required-number&quot;:true,&quot;validate-item-quantity&quot;:{&quot;minAllowed&quot;:1}}">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <button type="submit" title="In Winkelwagen" class="action primary tocart btn-block" id="product-addtocart-button">
            <span>In Winkelwagen</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you took that bootstrap code from. I tried with this links and it worked. Also better to add it as an external library rather than to put the code there directly.
For bootstrap 3 (css): https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css

For bootstrap 3 (js): https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js

For bootstrap 4 get the cdn from this link: https://getbootstrap.com